# How to shorten this code without using bunch of if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
CONSTANTS:

NDP_INDEX = 0
GREEN_INDEX = 1
LIBERAL_INDEX = 2
CPC_INDEX = 3
```

A dist of the indices where each party's data appears in a 4-element list.

```
PARTY_INDICES = [NDP_INDEX, GREEN_INDEX, LIBERAL_INDEX, CPC_INDEX]
```

A dict where each key is a party name and each value is that party's index.

```
NAME_TO_INDEX = {'NDP': NDP_INDEX,
'GREEN': GREEN_INDEX,'LIBERAL': LIBERAL_INDEX,'CPC': CPC_INDEX}
```

A dict where each key is a party's index and each value is that party's name.

```
INDEX_TO_NAME = {NDP_INDEX: 'NDP',GREEN_INDEX: 'GREEN', LIBERAL_INDEX:
'LIBERAL',CPC_INDEX: 'CPC'}


def voting_range(range_votes):
    ''' 
(list of list of int) -> tuple of (str, list of int)
#range_votes is a list of integers of range ballots for a single
#riding; the order of the inner list elements corresponds to the order
#of the parties in PARTY_INDICES.Based on range_votes, return a tuple
#where the first element is the name of the party winning the seat and
#the second is a list with the total range_votes for each party in the
#order specified in PARTY_INDICES.

>>> voting_range([[5, 4, 1, 4], [3, 2, 2, 5], [3, 3, 1, 4,]])
('CPC', [11, 9, 4, 13])

'''

NDP_count = 0
GREEN_count = 0
LIBERAL_count = 0

for sub_list in range_votes:
    NDP_count += sub_list[0]
    GREEN_count += sub_list[1]
    LIBERAL_count += sub_list[2]
    CPC_count += sub_list[3]

PARTY_INDICES[0] = NDP_count
PARTY_INDICES[1] = GREEN_count
PARTY_INDICES[2] = LIBERAL_count
PARTY_INDICES[3] = CPC_count

winner = max(NDP_count, GREEN_count, LIBERAL_count, CPC_count)
if winner == NDP_count:
    return 'NDP', PARTY_INDICES
elif winner == GREEN_count:
    return 'GREEN', PARTY_INDICES
elif winner == LIBERAL_count:
    return 'LIBERAL', PARTY_INDICES
elif winner == CPC_count:
    return 'CPC', PARTY_INDICES
```

I am not sure how to shorten this even with using helper function because we are not allow to create new constants (universal variables) but just local variables

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for sub_list in range_votes:
   for i in range(4):
       PARTY_INDICES[i] += sub_list[i]
return ( {PARTY_INDICES[0] : 'NDP', PARTY_INDICES[1] : 'GREEN', ...}[max(PARTY_INDICES)], 
         PARTY_INDICES )
```

That's as short as I'm willing to make it ;-)

Comment: You can make a second for i in range(4): PARTY_INDICES[i] += sub_list[0] to replace the assignments. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those dicts and range variables and define/enum looking things. This is a little less C and a little more python:

```
votes=[[5, 4, 1, 4], [3, 2, 2, 5], [3, 3, 1, 4,]]
parties=['NDP','GREEN','LIBERAL','CPC']

def voting_range(v):
  totals = [sum(x) for x in zip(*v)] # transpose row/col of list of lists
  pname = parties[totals.index(max(totals))]
  return (pname,totals)

>>> voting_range(votes)
('CPC',[11, 9, 4, 13])
```

There are a few magic python things going on here. [`*v`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) unpacks the list of lists, and feeds them as separate arguments to [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which returns an iterable that gives the first element of each argument in a list, then the second element of each argument in a list, and so on. This has the effect of transposing the matrix (swapping rows and columns). In this form, simply summing each list will be the vote totals. The `for x in` syntax wrapped in brackets is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), another awesome python feature which efficiently creates lists from iterables. Finally, `index` is a [list method](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) that will return the index of the first element that has the value specified, which in this case is the max. Since the elements of v should have the same length as the number of parties, this will also serve as the index into the parties list.

Comment: You can also move the parties definition inside the function if you're not allowed to augment (or in this case, reduce) the party definitions, or build it up from the existing definitions.